# How to make an active widget that calls a class

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to create a widget that can call a class which displays the information. Can somebody please tell me how to do it with the import files. If I ask dumb questions dont laugh.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Remoteviews. You can handle the  actions

Comment: I tried using PendingIntent but the widget is not working. Can you help me.

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797015/start-intent-from-android-widget-on-click/22799526#22799526